# Can the Reporting Tool in ArcMap connect to Auxiliary data, like Excel tables?

Tags: arcmap, excel, ms-access

Is it possible in ArcMap 10, using the reporting tool, to connect a report to non-spatial data, like from Excel or Access tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you add an Excel table to the ArcMap document before running the Report Wizard, that table is available to the Report Wizard (reporting tool).

The table doesn't need to be shown on the map, it just needs to be included in ArcMap's table of contents. To add it, click Add Data, navigate to then double-click the Excel file, and choose the appropriate table (worksheet) from the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is always true, but occasionally I had to refresh the layer to get the latest data from excel

Comment: Good point. I've seen similar issues where sometimes (but not always?) I've had to refresh with connections to external files.

Comment: If you convert the EXCEL table to a Geodatabase Table that will always be available - but just not convenient...